# PositionalDataSource при использовании Paging Library

Tags: android, android-room

Есть проект, в котором в зависимости от переключателя выводится один или другой список (в каждом примерно по 10 тыс. записей). Раньше проект использовал `SQLOpenHelper` и `Loader-ы`, но был переделан и сейчас работает через `Room` и `Pading Library`. Заметил что когда переключается на другой список (т.е. вместо одного выводится в `RecyclerView` другой), то второй список подгружается с задержкой где-то секунды 2-3, раньше было заметно быстрее. Хотелось бы узнать при использовании `Paging Library` обязательно ли использовать например `PositionalDataSource` и какие преимущества он дает? Позволит ли `PositionalDataSource` быстрее переключать списки? Сейчас сделано без него.

Comment: Ответьте пожалуйста да или нет? Сегодня переделал приложение включив DataSource но изменений не заметил. Для чего вообще его используют?

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. DataSource может быть разным источником, читай сервер или бд, то скорость работы с ним будет зависить от того, как он реализован. У вас данных много, поэтому нужно экспериментировать локально.

PositionalDataSource будет запрашивать данные с указанной позиции, то есть не все, а это уже хорошо, т.к. не нужно тащить все(касается соединения с сервером).

Вот тут подробнее про [DS](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/545-urok-17-paging-library-vidy-datasource.html).